# Upgrading msata Dell xps 14 ultrabook

Tags: cache, dell-xps, ahci, msata

I'm planning to upgrade the msata of my dell xps 14 to a Mushkin Atlas msata. 
Currently my machine has the intel caching enabled. When I upgrade the drive and switch the sata mode to AHCI, will the data on the main hdisk disk still be accessible or will I have to reformat the drive??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is still there and accessible when you switch from Intel rst to achi. 
Just take care not to install the intel ahci drivers, as the main hdisk with ahci is not compatible and will disappear in windows.